# frame widget in tkinter prevents child widgets from being displayed

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been trying to get to grips with tkinter as a gui builder in python.

I used a textbook tutorial to create the following which uses a frame widget to hold other widgets (suggested by author):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

app = Frame(root)

lbl = Label (app, text="This is a label")
lbl.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

This creates a window but the lbl object isn't created at all.  I have found precious little online but in testing I did discover that if I removed setting up the frame and just passed root as the master directly into the label constructor it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tkinter.Frame` widget needs to have its `grid` method called as well:

```
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
```

Otherwise, it will not be placed on the window.

Comment: Just to be clear: you don't have to call `grid` -- the other choices are `pack` and `place` (though `place` should be used very sparringly)